How to use LeftIndent in VBA?
Here is my code I'm using but didn't work, the property LeftIndent does not exist in the textRange-object.
Sub Puce_2nd_level()
    Dim slide As slide
    Dim shape As shape
    Dim textRange As textRange

    If Not ActiveWindow.Selection.textRange Is Nothing Then
        Set textRange = ActiveWindow.Selection.textRange

          
        With textRange.ParagraphFormat
            .LeftIndent = 3   '<-- This function doesn't exist
            .SpaceAfter = 3
            .Alignment = ppAlignLeft 
        '.FirstLineIndent =
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Veuillez sélectionner le texte auquel vous souhaitez ajouter une puce.", vbExclamation
    End If
    
End Sub 


It does not have this property indeed. Why do you expect it to?

You need to use property TextRange2 instead of TextRange, it has the LeftIndent-property:
Sub Puce_2nd_level()
    Dim slide As slide
    Dim shape As shape
    Dim tr2 As TextRange2

    If Not ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange2 Is Nothing Then
        Set tr2 = ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange2

        With tr2.ParagraphFormat
            .LeftIndent = 3
            .SpaceAfter = 3
            .Alignment = ppAlignLeft 
        End With

        Set tr2 = Nothing
    Else
        MsgBox "Veuillez sélectionner le texte auquel vous souhaitez ajouter une puce.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub 

